# Is the target of Hold Person completely still, or just held in place?

Tags: spells, adnd-2e

I DM a game in which the spell Hold Person was used recently and there was a dispute as to a minute detail which impacted the game seriously. The spell outlines that the affected individuals "cannot move or speak" and cannot use "motion."

In video games like *Icewind Dale* and *Baldur's Gate*, hold person still allows melee combat by a held creature if you come within melee range.

However, the mage's player thought that with lack of motion the held creature could not use his arms.

Would this not constitute paralyzation if one couldn't use any portion of their body? Seems OP or melee should be allowed.

How motionless does Hold Person make the affected creatures?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. The site is happy to help with older and out-of-print games, but the question's tags do need to indicate the system. (While this can oftentimes be inferred, the site's been wrong enough to make this mandatory.) Please add a system (probably `adnd-2e`), and I'm certain someone will offer assistance shortly. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: @DoctorKill (Your helpfulness is awesome, but it's usually better to let askers do it themselves. See this [Meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6867/8610).)

Comment: OK, will do in future.

Comment: I attempted dnd-2e from the popular tags list but it said I didn't have enough influence. I didn't try adding the "a"  thanks all.

Comment: @ErinThursby Please write your answer as one, not as a comment.

Comment: Your comment on the effects of "Hold person" in Baldurs Gate and Icewind Dale are incorrect.  Hold person does in fact, completely freeze a character.  Thus, making them ineffective in combat.

Comment: Its been a while, memory must've faded. Thanks again everyone, the Wiz-Kid will surely be tickled to have his interpretation confirmed!

Comment: for reference, in 5e, hold person does indeed cause paralysis. Of course, the two systems are vastly different, especially balance-wise, but it might provide indication what the intent behind the spell is.

Answer (score 17):

### By the Text of the Spell

> This spell holds 1d4 humans, demihumans, or humanoid creatures rigidly immobile for five or more rounds.

and

> Held beings cannot move or speak, but they remain aware of events around them and can use abilities not requiring motion or speech.

AD&D is famously open to DM interpretation, but I don't see how you could interpret that in any other way than *immobile.*

### Video Games

Baldur's Gate and Icewind Dale use "a modified version" of AD&D, which may allow for such inconsistencies. I'm not sure all the modifications they made.

The game itself seems to agree with the D&D game though (and I never remember a Held creature doing this, but haven't played the game in ages):

Status Effect "Held":

> The character is frozen for a number of seconds. They cannot move, attack, or use items.

Sources of the "Held" condition:

- Hold Person
- Hold Animal
- Ghast attack
- Shadow attack

### Attacks of Opportunity

These became available in the *Player's Option: Combat and Tactics* supplement.

> Attacks of opportunity occur when a threatened character or creature
>   ignores the enemy next to it or turns its back on a foe. The
>   threatening enemy gets to make an immediate melee attack (or sequence
>   of attacks for monsters with multiple attacks) against the threatened
>   creature. Attacks of opportunity cannot be performed with missile
>   weapons. This is a free attack that does not take the place of any
>   actions the threatening creature had already planned.

My best guess, maybe the creators of Baldur's Gate/Icewind Dale interpreted the spell differently than the obvious way it should be interpreted. Or, maybe their code for "do an attack of opportunity" superseded their code for "Held person" due to a bug.

Comment: Although not as infamous as [*dawizard*](https://selinker.livejournal.com/32929.html), that some fellow at TSR used the find-and-replace function to change every 1–4 to 1d4—an especially important (and inaccurate!) change in the *hold person* spell—is probably worth noting.